# Residuals in GARCH (1,1) is the same as the original data

Tags: r, time-series, residuals, garch, fitting

I am trying to fit a GARCH(1,1) model using the `rugarch` package. When I use `residuals` to extract the residuals, I find the data is the same as the original data, and I am not sure what's wrong with my code.

```r
> spec_2 <- ugarchspec(
+   variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1)),
+   mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0), include.mean = FALSE)
+ )
> garch_2 <- ugarchfit(spec = spec_2, data = y)
> head(residuals(garch_2))
                   [,1]
1970-01-02  0.002929857
1970-01-03  0.004497304
1970-01-04  0.001767694
1970-01-05  0.001019951
1970-01-06 -0.000185148
1970-01-07 -0.002509205

> head(y)
[1]  0.002929857  0.004497304  0.001767694  0.001019951 -0.000185148
[6] -0.002509205
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fine, because your GARCH model is
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \varepsilon_t, \\
\varepsilon_t &= \sigma_t z_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 \varepsilon_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2, \\
z_t &\sim i.i.N(0,1)
\end{aligned}
where the conditional mean equation (the top one) specifies that the unstandardized residuals $\varepsilon_t$ equal the raw series $y_t$. Meanwhile, standardized residuals $z_t$ are not equal to $y_t$, and you could see this if you specified that you want to extract the standardized residuals instead of the raw ones. You can do this by running `head(residuals(garch_2,standardize=TRUE))`.